# Normals porblems

Tags: modeling, normals, normal-map

My normals are correctly but they still "black". What is the solution for this? Already removed doubles but no sucess.

[image]

Comment: Have you flipped or recalculated the normals? It looks like blender may think that the normals are "inside" and are coloring them dark for that reason.

Comment: Thanks for the help already fixed by ctrl j and x>limited dissolve.